# Best way to import daily large amounts of data to a csv with Python

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, selenium-webdriver

I need to web scrape data with Python using Selenium, because the website where i get the data from creates content dynamically. Due to the large amount of data (rows) and the specific website, i will need to let the program run daily (maybe for a month). Eventually, al the data will be stored in a CSV file.

I was thinking on `insert` every row of data for each iteration to PostgreSQL and when I finish the scraping copy the table to a CSV file. My other option was keeping open the CSV file and `append` row by row with each iteration.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why not pandas?

Comment: Use [COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) avoid the overhead of Pandas.

Comment: I would use pandas too. May I recommend adding each row to a dataframe, then after you are done with that scraping cycle, you can convert dataframe to csv. Then csv directly to database. This limits the amount of calls on to your database

Comment: how much is a "large amount of data (rows)" are you prematurely optimizing? Is this a problem?

Comment: @EvanCarroll It's gonna be like 500k rows, 12 columns table

Answer (score 0):

From the [**docs**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/populate.html):

*"Note that loading a large number of rows using COPY is almost always faster than using INSERT.."*